# how can I read error messages from a properties file just like struts in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, struts

I am thinking of storing error messages in a properties file in my UI framework (angularjs). When a rest call fails, based on the error code I can read the messages from the file and show it on the UI. Similar to how struts handles this through messageresource properties. I tried to look up the angularjs doc but not getting any direction on how to do it. Any suggestions on how to achieve this feature in angularjs?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the ways to show error messages in your UI.

Create a json file *ErrorMessages* like this:

```
{
"ERROR-EDIT": "Some problems by updating the item!",
"ERROR-SAVE": "Some problems by saving the changes!",
"ERROR-DELETE": "Some problems by deleting!",
"ERROR-EMAIL": "E-Mail is not valid!"
}
```

To get the data from json file, in your controller you have to create http request to that file.

Providing that your module and other angular configuration is valid, the controller should be like:

```
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
//HTTP call to get data from file with valid url    
$http.get('../Resources/ErrorMessages.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.listMessages = data;
    });
}]);
```

And finally, the [key note](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_properties.asp) to display just one property of that object with key-value (explicit way):

```
<body ng-controller="mainController">

    <p>{{listMessages["ERROR-EDIT"]}}</p><br /><br />
    <p>{{listMessages["ERROR-DELETE"]}}</p><br /><br />
    <p>{{listMessages["ERROR-EMAIL"]}}</p><br /><br />
    <p>{{listMessages["ERROR-SAVE"]}}</p><br /><br />

</body>
```

You could also create function with parameteres including object and key to display it with the same result.

I hope this idea will push you forward :)

Comment: That should be on every controller. So while navigating to different pages it loads the same data again and again. There should be a better to initialize in the root scope but before any controller are initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Read about http-interceptors in Angular to handle global stuff like that. There is no concept of structs in Angular. Angular tries to keep its core fairly simple and includes only core stuff. You might want to write your own module using http interceptors to handle something like that.

You can write a error log service  and inject in all controllers where ever you want to log errors. That service can persist your log to Mongo or wherever

Comment: Could there be a simple properties files where I can just give a key value pair and based on the key display the value on the UI. Could this be done without interceptors ?

Comment: It can always be done without interceptors but the question is , on what level you want you want to do it. You can have a JSON file, write a service and have all error from json to some aaray in your error log service. Then inject this service in all controllers where you want to log error or show on UI.

Comment: Infact better than reading from a JSON file, create a CONSTANT object in which you can put as many key value pairs as possible. You still have to inject your constact in all service.

Best practices is, either you use a service with JSON file or a constant object, inject it on the parent most controller. It will be accessible in all child controllers.